# What is the fastest way to get the current time in C++11?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, time

Context:
I'm writing a high performance C++11 application, one part of it is to remove inactive connections. For that, I'm storing a "last activity" timestamp in my connection object, which I update when an action is taken. I then have a timer which runs every few seconds, loops over all sessions, and removes inactive ones.

Currently I'm using this code to get the current timestamp:

```
timestamp = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count()
```

I'm wondering if there is any faster way to do it? By faster I mean the performance of getting the timestamp itself, not the resolution of the timestamp.

The resolution is not really important for my specific application, it could go as low as a second. Also, utc/local doesn't matter, I am only using the timestamp to compare it to other timestamps, accquired by the same method.

I would like to keep it cross-platform, but platform-specific optimizations with conditional compilation are also welcome.

Comment: Why do you not simply do `timestamp = system_clock::now();`?

Comment: Have you *measured* that the timestamp-fetching is a bottleneck? Have you examined the (optimized!) generated machine code?

Comment: To add to @nwp, you can just check that `system_clock::now() - timestamp < timeout`.

Comment: And what are you going to *do* with the timestamp? Is it just saved and used internally? For timeout calculations possibly? Or are you saving it to file or sending it over a network connection? Or something else entirely? Your use-cases are also important to know for this.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The use case is in the first paragraph.

Comment: system_clock::now() is probably a kernel call, so it will be a bottleneck. Maybe run your own timer and just sync it with kernel each x minutes?

Comment: Then perhaps [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock), get a simple `now()` timestamp, and compare it with an earlier timestamp fetched in the same way? Try that, and *measure!* Use profilers (or even your own benchmarking) to check if it's really a bottleneck before you look for something else.

Comment: @nwp That could be an option, but `system_clock::now` returns a `chrono::time_point` object, which is 8 bytes. The timestamp I use is 4 bytes, so there's less memory overhead. Memory is not an issue in my case, but it's always a good idea to keep things small, for cpu cache optimizations. Though this is likely a micro-optimization. So, in the end, now that I thought about it while writing this reply - no particular reason really.

Comment: On a 64-bit system thew native word is eight bytes. Copying eight bytes is negligible, even on 32-bit systems. That's why it's so important to *measure* and *check the generated code*. Assumptions like yours leads to *premature optimizations* which are bad. Concentrate on writing good, readable, working and maintainable code. Then measure. And then find the bottlenecks, and only optimize the *worst* of them, with plenty of comments and documentation and testing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have indeed profiled it, and... It is actually not the bottleneck. But for simple commands such as pings, it does take a slight chunk of execution time, and we're trying to squeeze every last bit we can. *(should look into server load balancing soon)*.

Comment: If performance is really an issue, and accuracy isn't, then you might not need to use a timestamp at all.  Rather just keep a counter for each connection, and whenever activity occurs for the connection, reset the counter to zero.  Whenever your timer goes off, have it increment the counter for each connection, and disconnect any connection whose counter value rises above (N) (for whatever value of N you find works best)

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis: I think you should add information about the platform you're on, as otherwise there's no better solution than using the standard library (which can be slow, as you mentioned) - presumably you'll need a platform-dependent solution here.

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis In cases like this, it might be better to design an implementation that's easy to change later and simply use a "good enough" approach to differ the optimization work to when you notice a problem. For example, define a type alias or template your code to allow the type of clock used and just use one of the standard clocks. Later you'll be able to change the type of clock used, including a user-defined class with a compatible interface which can encapsulate any alternative solution you find. Most of the time you'll find that you never optimize it cause it's never a problem.

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis: btw, if you only query time once in a few seconds, this query won't be a bottleneck at all (so this would be an unnecessary optimization - you'll gain nothing from it).

Comment: @geza I'm getting the timestamp on any activity from any connected session, to update the last activity timestamp. And there are a lot of small actions happening from a lot of sessions constantly (pings and what not), that is the one I meant. The part where I do it every few seconds in a timer doesn't really matter, no.

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis: but why not update last activity with the last queried time? (Add some plus safety margin to the timeout value)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner That is actually a great idea! It would indeed work for my case, and even without doing any benchmarks I'm almost certain it will alleviate any performance cost the time querying has. I have no idea why I haven't thought of that, I do feel rather silly now. Would you mind writing that as an answer, so it would be more visible to others of similar fate (and I could likely accept it later on?)

Comment: @geza Yep, that would work. Should have thought of it myself too. If you don't mind, post an answer so everybody who looks this up sees it. May or may not be applicable to everyone's situation, but it's worth having it out there. Sort of as a way of "caching the current time".

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis: Now my question is, how do you exactly manage time query, so you can warrant that it is queried once in a few seconds? :)

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis: There are exactly 3 viable C++ standard library options for you: the C standard library function `time`, `std::steady_clock`, and `std::high_resolution_clock`. `system_clock` is *not* a viable solution for your needs, because the time returned by `system_clock` *can be changed*. If you set the time in your OS, `system_clock` will reflect that. `stable/high_resolution_clock` will not reflect changes to the OS time.

Comment: @geza I'm using Boost, in particular `boost::asio::deadline_timer`, waiting asynchronously. On the callback, I add a few seconds to the timer using `timer->expires_at(timer->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));` , and wait again. Almost exactly like in the tutorial here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html#boost_asio.tutorial.tuttimer4

Comment: @NicolBolas:  On gcc platforms `high_resolution_clock` and `system_clock` are the exact same type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If performance is really an issue, and accuracy isn't, then you might not need to use a timestamp at all. Rather just keep a counter for each connection, and whenever activity occurs for the connection, reset the counter to zero. Whenever your timer goes off, have it increment the counter for each connection, and disconnect any connection whose counter value rises above (N) (for whatever value of N you find works best)

Comment: And if you don't want the cleanup task timer precision to matter, have it record the time since it last ran and increment counters by *that much*.  Now you are generating a decent approximation of the OP's solution, and only calculating time *once* every few seconds on a non-performance criticlal thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a thread local variable per thread, and add a timerfd per thread (or you can use select/epoll timeout parameter) to wake the thread every 1 millsecond, when the select/epoll_wait return, you call now() to get the timestamp, and save the timestamp to the thread local variable.

you can also use a global variable, for example, std::atomic, and update it when select/epoll (in any threads) return. If you still think it's a bottleneck, use a single thread with timerfd and update the timestamp every 1 millsecond.